# Menu and Content div float left with a sticky footer -> height 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float, height, footer

i got a good question for the community.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto -65px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}
#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 220px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 130px 0 0 4%;
}
#contenu {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2% 5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Need this div to take 100% */
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#container_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="entete">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu2</li>
      <li>Menu3</li>
      <li>Menu4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="contenu">
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container_footer">
  <div id="footer">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is:
I need `#contenu` to take all the place to footer.
But! The content is dynamic ;)

When i got full content it work well but if i zoom out... Explosion!

I need absolutely the `float left` on the `#menu` and `#contenu` cause of  `#menu` that can be collapsed with a button click event.

I can put the code for the collapse but it work for this state so...

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Please See the modify code. As far as I understood your requirement, you need equal height of both the section. Now height of both the section will be equal. please correct me if I am wrong.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}
.table-display{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu {
  width: 20%;
  color: #ffffff;
 display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background:#57ad68;
}
#contenu {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ffffff; 
  color:#000;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#container_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="entete">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-display">
   <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu2</li>
      <li>Menu3</li>
      <li>Menu4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="contenu">
    <div style="min-height:550px;">
      <p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p><p>Your Content</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="container_footer">
  <div id="footer">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ty for your answer. I need in my example to got the "#contenu" (white section) to go down to the footer.
The div can be height equal ;) But my requirement is to have the right div which is float:left to be height 100; real...
hard to do this
I try to take this example but not working with my floating divs... (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Hi, Well in that case In my code, wrap the content which is inside  `#contenu` by a `<div>` and set it's `min-height:550px;`. You can adjust this min-height according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi thanks for this but in case we need to have a full dynamic content ;)
I'm pretty sure it's quite impossible to do this properly...

Comment: No then height will increase automatically. We are setting `min-height` only. When dynamic content will take more height than `550px` then height of div will also adjusting accordingly.

Comment: I know ;) But i'm not good explaining. 
We can have some popup with 1545878px height and if we don't have this height in the content we generate black background.. 
Same situation if we zoom out with no content. The min-Height is just a security

Comment: To help you, I need to see your actual code and problem. :)

Comment: I know but i can't ;)
but the generate html is exactly the same i post ;)
The structure i mean. Internal component are not important.

Comment: Yes I understand you can't show me your code. I think my code should work, try it once. One more thing you can try, you can use <table> structure also in-place of <div> structure for that particular part.